# Add Date Picker on to VBA UserForm for Excel 2013

Tags: excel, user-interface, datepicker, vba

Dear Members.

My question is about using "Calendar" on VBA UserForm and I know this kind of question was asked much in the Forum. Actually I researched and read reviews and comments of professionals written down on Forum. As the result I understood there is no option to add "Date Picker" on to Tool Box, on the other hand "Date Picker" is not shareable for other users.

So, I need date picker on VBA UserForm in Excel 2013 file which will be shareable.

Please, help me to identify the issue.

Comment: We are not a forum...

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks for clarification.